# swift UInt32 0 or 0x0?

Tags: swift, uint32

All the tutorials I look I see the number as 0x0 when is assigned to a UInt32

> self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0x0

why not

> self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0

is there a reason for it or just for readability ?

Comment: There is no difference at all. But for a bit mask, `0x0200` *might* be clearer than `512`, other people prefer `1 << 9`.

Comment: Is this the tutorial from ray wenderlich? I think it's just the author's preference.

Comment: so in case of 512 I assume it can be written as...1 <<9, 2^9, 0x0200 or any combination that is equivalent ?

Comment: Is from a Coursera class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference between `0` and `0x0`, but it's written that way because the property in question is a bit mask, which can be easier to look at in hex. Probably elsewhere, other values will be written as `0x0010` and such, so they've chosen to write `0x0` for consistency's sake. It's a personal preference, so in your own code, feel free to use hex, binary, or even the bit shift operator (`1 << 3`)—whatever helps you understand the constants and the way they interact as bit masks.